# Connection between orbits and stabiliziers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the lecture we learned the following:

> Let $X$ be a set, $G$ a group and $x,y\in X$. For a given group operation, we have: $G\ast x=G\ast y\Rightarrow G_x \cong G_y$ ($G\ast x$ is the orbit and $G_x$ the stabilizier of $x$).

Now I've been wondering: Is the opposite direction true as well? So that the above statement becomes: $G\ast x=G\ast y\Leftarrow G_x \cong G_y$? When I try to look at some examples, it seems to be the case, but I can't think of a proof. Or perhaps, it's not true to begin with? In that case, what would a counterexample look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, take the trivial action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ (i.e. $g*x=x$ for all $g$ in $G$ and $x$ in $X$). Then $G_x=G$ for each $x$ but every orbit is a singleton.